# Change selection color of ListBox Item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, listbox

I have a normal `ListBox` and I want to change the selection color to Red. Here's what I've got so far.

```
<Style x:Key="myLBStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
                         Color="red" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}"
                         Color="red" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

It's working. The SelectedItem is Red and stay Red even if it's out of focus.

Here's my real problem: In my grid I also have a `CheckBox` and I want the above style to apply only if the CheckBox is checked.

So if the CheckBox is checked i want the selection color to be Red and to be Blue (or default color) if the CheckBox is unchecked.

I went through the web and i can't find anything, so i'm looking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two separate styles -

1. Default style with all your setter and triggers.
2. Blank style with resources defined in it and make this style to be **`BasedOn`** default style so that all setters and triggers gets inherited from default style.

And then you can swap **`ItemContainerStyle`** based on checkBox checked state.

---

Sample :

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="myLBStyleDefault">
          <!-- All setters and triggers go here -->
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="myLBStyleWithRed"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource myLBBaseStyle}"
               TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush
                    x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
                    Color="Red" />
                <SolidColorBrush
                    x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}"
                    Color="Red" />
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <CheckBox x:Name="chk"/>
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ListBox">
                <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle"
                        Value="{StaticResource myLBStyleDefault}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chk}" 
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle"
                                Value="{StaticResource myLBStyleWithRed}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Style>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do that in code by handling the [`CheckBox.Checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.checked(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`CheckBox.Unchecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.unchecked(v=vs.110).aspx) events as I don't believe that you can add or remove `Resources` using a `Trigger` in XAML. However, the [properties of the `SystemColors` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.SystemColors_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) are read only, so you can't set them directly either.

There is one way that I found, but that involves importing the `kkk` method from the `user32.dll`, so it might not be for the feint hearted. For more information, please see the [SetSysColors (user32)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SetSysColors) page on the pinvoke.net website. From the linked page:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
 public static extern bool SetSysColors(int cElements, int [] lpaElements, int [] lpaRgbValues);
 public const int COLOR_DESKTOP = 1;

 //example color
 System.Drawing.Color sampleColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;

 //array of elements to change
 int[] elements = {COLOR_DESKTOP};

 //array of corresponding colors
 int[] colors = {System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToWin32(sampleColor)};

 //set the desktop color using p/invoke
 SetSysColors(elements.Length, elements, colors);

 //save value in registry so that it will persist
 Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\\Colors", true);
 key.SetValue(@"Background", string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", sampleColor.R, sampleColor.G, sampleColor.B));
```