# Change Color of a selected Row in a Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to change the Color of a Listview Row in XAML when I:

1. Have the Cursor over it
2. Have the Row selected

I tried many different Solutions I found here in the Forum and also on other websides, but I never found a solution that really changed any of the Color. I just get it to Change the text Color when I select a Item but thats not what I want.
Maybe someone can help me, this is my XAML Listview:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" x:Name="listBox2" Margin="269,32,10.286,0" Height="119" VerticalAlignment="Top" Drop="DropEvent" AllowDrop="True">
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn 
            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path}"
            Width ="1000"/>
         </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
   </ListView>
</ListView>
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936938/change-selection-color-of-listbox-item

Answer (score 4):

You could define an `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" x:Name="listBox2">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}" Width="1000"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```